# Is there a meeting on cancel feature in Outlook add-ins like on send

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to develop a simple meeting room JavaScript add-in for Outlook, where any meeting booked/cancelled in Outlook, also reflects in my meeting room system (NodeJS with simple rest APIs).

I'm able to catch any bookings made from Outlook successfully using [on send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/officedev/outlook-add-in-on-send/outlook-add-in-on-send-code-sample/) add-ins.
My problem arises when a user cancels/reschedules the meeting from Outlook/Outlook OWA/calendar; it does not seem like the on send add-in catches these events.
An option right now, is to periodically do a sync for any cancellation/reschedule, which does not seem like the asynchronous way to go.

1. Is there any way to catch the **cancellation** and **reschedule** meeting event and make a REST API call from Outlook (add-ins?) to my meeting room system? *On all platforms, Outlook desktop/OWA/Calendar.*
2. Can add-ins catch these events like cancel and reschedule, on a few platforms (Despktop/OWA) maybe?

Am I going about this all wrong?
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!!

Comment: on send add-ins also run for cancel and reschedule if the organizer brings up the form to send the cancellation or update. Are you referring to the cases when user can cancel without opening the meeting event?

Comment: Oh I'll verify for cancel and reschedule from event form, thank you! 

Yes I am concerned about the cases when user can cancel without opening the meeting event, for ex from calendar.

Comment: Currently the feature:"Cancel without opening Event form", you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our  user voice page https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Hey cancel from the event form in Outlook on the web (see (screenshot)[https://imgur.com/a/igkxrKO], is this the one?) does not activate the add-in. 

Can you show me how to cancel in OWA that activates the add-in?

Comment: Sorry, the event detects that the user is pressing the "Send" button (or the "Send Update" button for existing meetings) and can be used to block the item from sending, if the validation fails. It does not cover cancel button. You should be able to catch reschedule scenario because it is under "Send Update". We recommend you to create a [user voice request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) for cancel scernarios.

Comment: Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT, user voice request[https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins] does not exists, can you suggest where we can request for this feature.